# How to set node taint for memcached using mcrouter helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm using the [mcrouter helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mcrouter) to setup mcrouter on GKE. For my setup I'd like to have a dedicated node pool for the memcached statefulset and a daemonset for mcrouter.

I'm [creating the node pool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create) with a taint using the `--node-taints` flag. To ensure that the memcached statefulset can run on this node pool I need to specify `tolerations` as described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/.

How do I specify the toleration? I'm currently creating my setup using helm as follows:

> helm install stable/mcrouter --name=mycache --set memcached.replicaCount=15 --set memcached.resources.requests.memory=10Gi --set memcached.resources.requests.cpu=2 --set resources.requests.memory=512Mi --set resources.requests.cpu=1.5 --set resources.limits.memory=512Mi --set resources.limits.cpu=2 --set memcached.memcached.maxItemMemory=8432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Helm Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mcrouter) doesn't support it.

After you create the DaemonSet you can patch it. For example (change to whatever toleration you want):

```
$ kubectl patch daemonset mycache-mcrouter -p='{"spec":{"template": {"spec":  {"tolerations": [{"key": "key1", "operator": "Equal", "value": "value1", "effect": "NoSchedule"}]}}}}'
```

You can also upstream a change to support tolerations. You would have to add variables in the `values.yaml`(https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mcrouter/values.yaml) file and then optionally use it in the [`daemonset.yaml`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mcrouter/templates/daemonset.yaml) template.

Comment: Thanks, patching should do the trick. But just curious, what would have to change in daemonset.yaml? I thought modifying this would affect mcrouter and not the memcached statefulset.

Comment: You probably need to add a condition like `{{- if eq .Values.tolerations "enabled" }} .... {{- end }}`  under spec.template.spec